# Linking of forms: How to access Checkboxes in c#?

Tags: c#, checkbox

I have form1 and form2, on form1 i have a checkbox1, i need to know on form2 that, that checkbox1 is enabled. Please Help! I'm making an arithmethic learning system that has settings on the first form, so if addition is checked(checkbox1), the form 2 will perform addition equations.

Comment: Can you post your code here?

Answer (score 1):

First - you really need to include ***code***...

However - assuming your checkboxes have been added by the designer - all you have to do is to go to the properties of the checkbox and set the 'Modifiers' for that control to 'Public':

[image: The Modifiers Designer Property]

Then, assuming you have a reference to `Form1` you should see your checkbox appear in intellisense in the list of members.

Note that this is the shortest and easiest way to expose the control - whether it's the *most sensible* way to do it is another matter.  But for simple, closed projects, it's perfectly reasonable.